# Python 'except' clauses not working

Tags: python, nameerror, except

Hello Stack Overflow community.

I'm currently trying to learn how to program in Python (3.5) and I've had a problem with a conversion program. Summarised, it seems like Python is ignoring the except clauses in the source code.

```
try:
    print("Welcome to CONVERSION. Choose an option.")
    print("1. Convert CELSIUS to FAHRENHEIT.")
    print("2. Convert FAHRENHEIT to CELSIUS.")
    Option = int(input("OPTION: "))
except NameError:
    print(Option, " is not a valid input.")
except ValueError:
    print(Option, " is not a valid input.")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Don't do that!")
else:
    if (Option != 1) or (Option != 2):
        print("Please input a valid option!")
    elif (Option == 1):
        try:
            Celsius = float(input("Enter value in Celsius: "))
        except ValueError:
            print(Celsius, " is not a valid input.")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Don't do that!")
        else:
            Fahrenheit = Celsius * 1.8 + 32
        print(Celsius, "C = ", Fahrenheit, "F.")
    elif (Option == 2):
        try:
            Fahrenheit = float(input("Enter value in Fahrenheit: "))
        except ValueError:
            print(Celsius, " is not a valid input.")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Don't do that!")
            Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * ( 5 / 9 )
            print(Fahrenheit, "F = ", Celsius, "C.")
        else:
            print("That value is invalid. Try again.")
```

The full traceback, when inputting the value "wad" in the first screen:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TempConversion\TempConversion\TempConversion.py", line 7, in <module>
Option = int(input("OPTION: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'wad'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TempConversion\TempConversion\TempConversion.py", line 11, in <module>
print(Option, " is not a valid input.")
NameError: name 'Option' is not defined
```

Comment: Please read the Error carefully: What happens is that your program tries to convert "wad" into an integer on line 7 which of course fails. It catches the error and rethrows on line 11 and error since Options is not define since the integer conversion fails. So please sanatize your input.

Comment: the `Option` is never defined since `int('wad')` returns an error. While handling it you try to print `Option` which again is not defined so another error is raised which this time is not handled. So it works well ☺

Comment: Not relevant to the question itself, but the convention in python is lower_case for functions / variables and UpperCase for class names. Also you don't need parens around the `if` conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is thrown after you caught an exception. This basically puts it outside the try catch scenario.

If you add `Option = None` before `try` the code should execute properly.

The reason for this is because `int(input(...))` raises an exception before Option is defined. So that the code that handles the initial exception is throwing a new exception.

You would also need to change the print statement inside the exception handling to properly handle a potential `None` value from `Options`. You could achieve this by something similar to this.

```
Option = None
try:
    Option = int(input("OPTION: "))
except (NameError, ValueError):
    if Option:
        print(Option, " is not a valid input.")
    else:
        print("No valid input.")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print("Don't do that!")
else:
   .....
```

This also applies to the similar code you have for Celsius and Fahrenheit.

[Edit] Not sure what is wrong for you now, ideally you should create a new question, as your new question is beyond the scope of your original question, but I prepared a quick, more slightly structured example based on your code.

```
import sys


def get_input(text, convert_to='int'):
    result = None
    try:
        if convert_to == 'int':
            result = int(input(text))
        else:
            result = float(input(text))
    except (NameError, ValueError):
        if result:
            print(result, " is not a valid input.")
        else:
            print("No valid input.")
        sys.exit(1)

    return result


def handle_celsius_to_fahrenheit():
    celsius = get_input('Enter value in Celsius: ', convert_to='float')
    fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32
    print("C = %s, F %s." % (celsius, fahrenheit))


def handle_fahrenheit_to_celsius():
    fahrenheit = get_input('Enter value in Fahrenheit: ', convert_to='float')
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9)
    print('F = %s , C %s.' % (fahrenheit, celsius))


def get_option():
    option = get_input('OPTION: ')
    if option == 1:
        handle_celsius_to_fahrenheit()
    elif option == 2:
        handle_fahrenheit_to_celsius()
    else:
        print("Please input a valid option!")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Welcome to CONVERSION. Choose an option.")
    print("1. Convert CELSIUS to FAHRENHEIT.")
    print("2. Convert FAHRENHEIT to CELSIUS.")
    get_option()
```

Comment: i would also move the initial `print` statements outside the `try` since there is nothing to _try_ there

Comment: Yep, agree. No reason to wrap those prints statements.

Comment: Although the first problem was solved, I'm having another one that didn't show up before. Whenever I input the values 1 or 2, which would supposedly trigger either the Celsius or Fahrenheit conversion, they instead trigger the if (Option != 1) or (Option != 2) code block.

Comment: @Walrus Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use variable `Option` in your string with error, but that variable doesn't exist, as it's the reason of the error. Try initiating `Option = input()` before the `try`  and convert it to int in `try`

Answer (score 0):

It works as it should. When you're handling the `ValueError` exception, you try to read `Option`, which is not set yet. This results in another exception. which you don't catch anymore.